# Rails 4 and mailboxer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing some Bloging app and I want to implement some private messaging system. I've instaled gem called mailboxer but there is a problem because it's not compatible with Rails 4. When I'm trying to send message to other user from rails console i have an error:

```
RuntimeError: `attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one.
from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails4/gems/activemodel-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_model/deprecated_mass_assignment_security.rb:14:in `attr_accessible
```

I don't wan't to install 'protected_attributes', i want to do it in Rails 4 way but i don't know how to do that...
Could anyone help?

Comment: It looks like the gem you have is in the middle of finding active developers for it so you may have to wait some time before it will work on rails 4. Options are probably limited to fixing the gem yourself, writing the functionality yourself or playing the wait game.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `gem 'protected_attributes'` in your Gemfile or use [strong params](http://rubysource.com/rails-4-quick-look-strong-parameters/) introduced in Rails 4 by default.

If you use strong params, you can do it like this (example taken from [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4?view=asciicast)):

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:name, :content, :published_at) # require is for mandatory and permit for optional parameters
end
```

And then you call:

```
@article.update(article_params)
```

Comment: i don't wan't to use protected_attributes because if i use it i will must refactor many models to use attr_accessible...

Comment: From protected_attributes documentation: "This plugin adds attr_accessible and attr_protected in your models."

Comment: I wan't to follow rails 4 way so i think the best way will be to crate my own messaging system.

Comment: If you want to follow rails 4, then strong params is the way. attr_accessible is replaced by strong params.

Comment: Yes i know that but i don't know how to do to mailboxer use strong params than attr_accessible...

Comment: I included a link about strong params in my original post, but I have updated it now. I hope it is more clear now, but be sure to read the article from the link.